# Method listings when typing '.' after an object

Tags: eclipse

Normally when you put the '.' after an object and wait you get a list of methods/fields/classes that one can access. My eclipse no longer does this for me. I spent 10-15 minutes searching for a way to turn it back on and I came up empty. How can I turn this back on?

Comment: Does Ctrl+Space show code completions?

Comment: @alex c It shows completions only for templates

Comment: Usually this happens because either eclipse (less likely) or your project (more likely) got into a bad state.  If your project is small, you might consider hand-transferring to a new project.  If it is large, doing a revert might work.  If neither of these are options, hunt down your errors; as John suggests in his answer, that can sometimes be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try mucking around in

`Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist`

and see what you get.  I've had this once before; eclipse got into a bad state and wouldn't code complete for a given project.  Reverting changes in the project got rid of some errors and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java you need to look at setting Java -> Editor -> Content Assist. You want to make sure that "Enable auto activation" is checked and the other options are set to your taste. The auto activation trigger should be the period.

It may not work if you have an error in your code.

Comment: It says auto activation is enabled and the trigger is '.'

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse and ensured you don't have any syntax erors?

Comment: You can also check the `Advanced` section of `Content Assist`; some plugins for Mylyn will change the settings there.

Comment: I suppose you could try the classic turn off auto activation, restart Eclipse, and then turn it on again.  Did you install any additional Eclipse packages?

Comment: alex c with the save: Under Advanced, "Java Proposals" was turned off.